# relinking missing files isn't working

Tags: linked-data, path

I'm  moving files to an external drive. One of my blend files shows textures fully pink. I could individually replace the paths of every model but that's about 100 models with several textures each.

Research on this issue hasn't been kind to me. You can go into File->External Data->Find Missing Files, but even though I know where the textures are and I'm sitting right in the directory, blender continues to complain that the files are not found.

My *find missing files* isn't working, not even when the texture names don't contain any special characters or anything that'd prevent the files from being found.

I'm on 2.77. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, for blender to not be able to find the project files in a new location.

Comment: Just to be sure, you haven’t changed the file names, have you?

Comment: no. none of the actual file names are different. just the directories.

Comment: That is odd for find missing files not to be working if you gave it the right directory path.

Comment: Hello :). Any error message like "Texture so and so couldn't be found"? Or the textures just don't load?

Comment: When paths are static, blender will only look for the textures in a fixed path. If the folder does't exist, or the textures now live in a different place, blender will never find them, as there in no tool to recursively look in all directories. Try switching to relative paths (//). By using relative paths, blender use the elements that are in the same directory as the .blend file.  To keep your sanity, you can also just copy the files to the external drive with the same folder structure, and create symbolic links, or alias for the operating system to redirect search queries to the new folders.

Comment: It usually says -texture path and directory- couldn't be found

Comment: i've attempted swapping the paths of the files to relative. it says they failed to do so for some reason.